# Hide certain nodes in view listing for anonymous users

Tags: views, nodes, 8

I am trying to restrict node access for anonymous users based on a custom field. 
I got it working for accessing the node directly like this:

```
$country = "GB";
if ($node->hasField('field_country_hide')) {
  $country_code = $node->field_country_hide->value;

  if ($country_code == $country) {
    // this user should not be allowed to see this article
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
} else {
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

But this doesn't restrict access for the node in a view listing. 
What is the best way to go about hiding a node in a view listing?

Comment: is this a page view or block view?

Comment: The answer that I have in mind depends on it, so please specify.

Comment: @NoSssweat it is a page view.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal doesn't evoke [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/8.2.x) when executing a view; it's querying the DB directly to get the data. As such, you're not going to be able evoke the same PHP snippet to have Views filter the result.

The "best" way (read: simple) is to have views create a query filter that does the same thing; you can add a  *Content: Country Hide* filter (or whatever your custom field is named) with the **Operator** set to *Is equal to* and the **Value** set to *GB*.

That will filter the nodes as you need, but you'll still need to provide the *context* (i.e. is the user anonymous or not). Here it's unclear. There's no "best" because there's not one way to provide context and it will depend on your needs.

One idea that comes to mind is to add 2 View blocks, one with the *GB* filter and one without, and set the block to display depending on the user role. But again, this will depend on your requirements. There's always custom [Views integration](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_overview/8.2.x) or, if you want to go the site builder route, other modules that provide context like [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context), [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels), etc.

Comment: That's the same idea I had in mind, use different view blocks and change the access from [permission](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jT5dg.png) to role. Since @Janey is using a page view, she could have an empty page view and create 2 different attachments instead of blocks, or create a custom module or custom node to create a custom path where she puts those view blocks in.

Answer (score 0):

For doing access control on views, i used the hook_views_post_execute.

To hide certain nodes for anonymous user,  it can be something like this

```
 function my module_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view)
 {

$user=\Drupal::currentUser();
$userRole=$user->getAccount()->getRoles();
$anonymous=$user->isAnonymous();


if ($view->id() == 'your_view_machine_name') {
foreach ($view->result as  $elementKey => $result ) {
    $node=$result->_entity;  
    $anonymous_hidden=$node->field_intranet_only->getValue();

    // Remove node if no rights
    if (($anonymous_hidden[0]['value'] == true) && ($anonymous==true) ){
          unset($view->result[$elementKey]);
    }
}
}
 }
```