# node access not taken in account in views

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

using the hook_node_access, i can restrict access to content by role.

If the boolean field_private_only is selected , only the user with the role private can view it, fine.

```
 my_module_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {

  global $user;
  if ($node->bundle() == 'my_content_type') {
      if ($op == 'view') {
          if ($node->field_private_only->getString()) {
            $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
            if($user->hasRole('private'))
               return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::allowed();
          }
      }
   }
 return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::forbidden();
}
```

When creating a view displaying these contents, the restriction does not occur .

How can i Make it happen in views?

how can i make it happens in search_api index ?

Comment: see [Hide certain nodes in view listing for anonymous users](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211261/hide-certain-nodes-in-view-listing-for-anonymous-users/211308#answer-211308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing access control on views, i used the hook_views_post_execute.

For nodes with a restricted_content field set to true, the content is shown or not depending on roles

```
 function my module_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view)
 {
$VIP_member=false;
$user=\Drupal::currentUser();
$userRole=$user->getAccount()->getRoles();

if (( $user!=null )&&(in_array('VIP_member',$userRole))){
    $VIP_member=true;
}

if ($view->id() == 'articles_list') {
    foreach ($view->result as  $elementKey => $result ) {
        $node=$result->_entity;        

        $VIP_restricted=$node->field_VIP_only->getValue();

        // Remove node if no rights
        if (($VIP_restricted[0]['value'] == true) && ($VIP_member==false) ){
              unset($view->result[$elementKey]);
        }
    }
}
 }
```